# Why is mobx observable property of js class not tracked, but property of mobx observable object is?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I'm new to mobx and I wanted to do a quick test of Mobx to see how can I fit it to my project.

When I run this code

```
class Entity{
   @observable version = 1;
}

let testEntity = new Entity();

let disposer = autorun(() => console.log(`Entity version : ${testEntity.version}`));

testEntity.version = 2;
testEntity.version = 3;

disposer();
```

I expect to see this output

```
Entity version : 1
Entity version : 2
Entity version : 3
```

But, instead, I see only `Entity version: 1`

But if I use an observable plain object instead of class with observable properties, I get the desired output. Example:

```
let testEntity = observable({ version: 1 });

let disposer = autorun(() => console.log(`Entity version : ${testEntity.version}`));

testEntity.version = 2;
testEntity.version = 3;

disposer();
// this works and I see autorun firing three times instead of only the first.
```

So I thought I should make the class instance observable.

I used `let testEntity = observable(new Entity());` but this threw an error about some `.box` function.

I tried again, this time with `let testEntity =observable.box(new Entity());` and I had no errors.

But this time I got this result `Entity version: undefined`

What is going on here, and how can I achieve observable class instances?

Maybe I am following the wrong approach to my problem. I want to have my domain objects as class instances to add some business logic, and data manipulation inside them.

I have read the article about what mobx tracks and what it doesn't track, but it seems I still miss something.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t used `autorun` a lot, but I think problem is that you’re calling `autorun` outside of the class. Try moving that line of code to within your class:

```
class Entity{
   @observable version = 1;

   let disposer = autorun(() => console.log(`Entity version : ${version}`));
}

let testEntity = new Entity();



testEntity.version = 2;
testEntity.version = 3;

testEntity.disposer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the example, however, I tested your code and **it works perfectly fine** and we even don't need to save the return from `autorun` in the disposer. 
Following is the test snippet, which works perfectly, i.e. it prints console 3 times, with updated values.

```
import { observable, autorun } from 'mobx';
class Entity {
  @observable version = 1;
}

let testEntity = new Entity();

autorun(() => console.log(`Entity version : ${testEntity.version}`));

testEntity.version = 2;
testEntity.version = 3;
// prints
Entity version : 1
Entity version : 2
Entity version : 3

----------------------------------------

/* Taking autorun inside class is fine either */
class Entity {
  @observable version = 1;
  disposer = autorun(() => console.log(`Entity version : ${this.version}`));
}
```